# How can I download a drive non-google file (e.g. PDF) in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I have been experimenting with this for a while but could not find a fix for this automation.

I have a spreadsheet app that I use for tracking work performed for a client.  Each job is a row in the spreadsheet and it can generate PDF invoices in drive when the job is complete.

Now, I want to improve the invoice automation.  I want to add a "download invoice" menu item to google sheet that starts a download of the pdf to the local computer for later sending on to a client.   I currently do this stage manually and it is a little error-prone.

I know how to add menu items so that bit is fine.

My downloadFile function is below and from looking in the log it appears to work ok - it returns http 200 and 53000 bytes (correct size) but no file appears. What I would like is something like a "save as dialog box"  open when I hit the menu.

I suspect that I have to associate the download with a GUI component but not really sure how to progress that bit.

```
/** start a download dialog for a PDF file so I can save it on the c: drive */
function downloadFile()
{
  // invoicesFolderID is the folder ID defined elsewhere
  var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(invoicesFolderID);
  Logger.log("reading from folder: " + theFolder.getName() + " " + theFolder.getId());

  // fixed filename for testing
  var filename = "Invoice_xyz.pdf";
  var matchingFileList = theFolder.getFilesByName(filename);
  Logger.log("matchingFileList: has files? " + matchingFileList.hasNext());

  // don't allow duplicates
  if (matchingFileList.hasNext())
  {
    f = matchingFileList.next()    
    Logger.log("filename=" + f.getName());
    Logger.log("ID="       + f.getId());
    Logger.log("URL="      + f.getDownloadUrl());

    var options = {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        // tried various http methods
        "method" : "get",
      }  
    };

    // believe that alt=media needs to be added for pdf files
    var httpResp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(f.getDownloadUrl() + "?alt=media", options);
    Logger.log("http repsonse " + httpResp.getResponseCode());
    Logger.log("http headers  " + httpResp.getHeaders().toSource());
    Logger.log("http headers len  " + httpResp.getContent().length);
    // tried adding this 
    //var pdf = httpResp.getAs('application/pdf');

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Use [getDownloadUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdownloadurl) to get the URL to be used to download the file then add that URL to a UI link or button to be clicked by the user.

## Remarks

**getDownloadURL** will return a temporary URL that will work for a short period of time.

There are several Q&A in StackOverflow that refers to the [Class Anchor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/anchor). Bear in mind that it's now deprecated.

## Related

[Unable to serve download links in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209390/unable-to-serve-download-links-in-google-apps-script/27234775#27234775)

Comment: Thanks Ruben,  you have set me in the right direction.  The UI stuff is not something I have looked at and now I see it is replaced by HTML service. I created a little UI, panel with  a link.  When I click the link (with google.com) in it, that page loads in a new tab.  When I use my own document.getDownloadURL() link the new tab contains the URL but appears blank.  Perhaps this is persmissions, so I will continue to experiment.

Comment: Yep.  Just changed the script to add two links, one with google doc and one with word doc in a public dropbox folder.  The dropbox one worked straight away. . . I'll experiment - sounds like content type problem or permissions prob.  I suspect the former.